# Create, Update, Delete in Sql and Read from NoSql with SpringBoot and JPA

Tags: database, algorithm, design-patterns, database-design

Here is my requirement:

1. I would need to use Sql db to perform Create, Update and Delete operations
2. I would need to use NoSql to perform Read operations

a)I understand that Create, Update and Delete transactions offer better performance in Sql DB.

b)I understand that Read transactions offer better performance in NoSql DB.

What are the disadvantages of me using Table_PER_CLASS and JOINED, InheritanceType, rather than SINGLE_TABLE for modelling my data persistence layer?

This is a solution I envision:
Every time a Create, Update, Delete transaction is performed a mechanism would update the NoSql data accordingly.

Am I going in the right direction with my thought process. Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand the "need" for an SQL and a NoSQL database.  If your data can be normalized, use an SQL database.  If not, use a NoSQL database.  If some data can be normalized and some data can't, use an SQL database for the data that can be normalized and a NoSQL database for the data that can't be normalized.

Comment: the READ is faster in NOSQL. that is the need for NoSQL in my opinion.

Comment: Then use a NoSQL database.

Comment: what about the strategy for modelling the sql db for the update mechanism to be easy to be build. what am I giving up if I use one strategy over the other?

Comment: Seems like extra work for no benefit to me.  Surely, there must be a NoSQL database that allows you to easily insert, update, or delete information.

Comment: sure there are solutions, that;s not the point of this conversation. the question was around the strategies to design the Sql DB relation.